# Screenshots of all android.R.layout built in layouts Android Studio

Tags: android

I was writing code to populate a listView and as I monotonously chose simple_list_item_1 for the 1 millionth time, I thought, "Hmm... What do all of these other built in layouts look like? If I knew I could maybe utilize them and save time and resources!"

After searching a plethora of different sites including even the android docs, I was unsuccessful. It sure would be helpful if some kind, genius programmer could compile several screenshots that maybe show a generic look of what each of these android.R.layout layout's look like and post it on StackOverflow so that I and many others could favorite and refer to said list during our code writing. That sure would be swell!

Hopefully this won't be too difficult of an ask.

----Or---

Is there someplace to preview each layout so we can chose one to use? I hear that eclipse has such a feature but I use Android Studio and have yet to find one.

Comment: I think the android built in layouts are similar with a little difference.

Comment: yea but it would be nice to see whether it is ascending textviews or horizontal textviews etc etc

Comment: Also me I tried to discover them and I agree with you and hope to see the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

You got all assets locally in

```
<SDK>/platforms/<VERSION>/data/res/
```

so you can view, copy, screenshot, whatever as you like if needed.

Comment: You're right, that's definitely where you can find everything pre-loaded to android including any/all the icon images and the layout files, but it doesn't serve as a convenient layout previewer...